# "Invalid file" error while uploading pdf from iCloud drive in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipart

I need to upload documents from iPhone to the application server, for that I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController and I have successfully picked the file from iCloud drive but when I am uploading file using alamofire multipart I am getting error msg from backend "invalid file".

I have converted the URL received from UIDocumentPickerViewController to Data before uploading. Here is my complete code:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        self.urlfilepick = url
        self.filePickedBlock?(url)

        stringpath = self.urlfilepick.path
        print(stringpath)

        thefileExtension = (stringpath as NSString).lastPathComponent
        thefileExtension = thefileExtension.replacingOccurrences(of: "Response Format :-.", with: "")

        UserDefaults.standard.set( thefileExtension , forKey: "fromdocument")

        stringcomingFrom = "Files"

    parameters = ["user_id":UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userid") ?? "","treatment_id":self.treatmentId!,"document_type_id":strdocumnetid,"label_name":self.txtdocumnetName.text!,"type":"1","ext":thefileExtension,]

           let datadat = NSData(contentsOfFile: stringpath)
           data = datadat as Data?
        self.requestWith(data: data, fileName: "file", pathExtension: thefileExtension, parameters: parameters)


    }
```

and the alamofire upload function is:

```
func requestWith(
                     data: Data?,
                     fileName: String?,
                     pathExtension: String?,
                     parameters: [String : Any]){

        guard let emailId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email") else {return}
        guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") else {return}
        let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json","med-token":token,"user":emailId,"device":"1"]


        let URL = baseUrl + uploadDocuments
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
            }

            if let data = data {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "filename", fileName: "\(fileName!).\(pathExtension!)", mimeType: "\(fileName!)/\(pathExtension!)")
            }

        }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: URL, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    print(response)

                    if let err = response.error {

                        return
                    }

                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            }
        }
    }
```

It is working fine in Postman.

Comment: Try `"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"` in header...

Comment: still getting the same error